# ccna: Collision domain vs broadcast domain

Tags: broadcast

I am currently preparing for CCNA I have a screenshot of CCNA online test.

I don't remember if I got it right or not. I think[image] there are 2 broadcast domain (circle with hand on the picture) and 5 collision domain (with circles). I am right?

[image]

Comment: Education and certification questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Router links are down and two workstations are offline, the correct answer should be that there are 4 collision domains and 2 broadcast domains